# Implementing Apple's Assistive touch like feature in my app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, appstore-approval

I have implemented something similar to Apple's assistive-touch in my app. Its a small view that floats around the screen and contains a few most commonly used functionalities in my app. Inside my app user can choose to show/hide the view.

However, I am not sure whether Apple is going to approve it. Please share your views.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried on this? I want same functionality?

Comment: have you tried on this? I want same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this view is a common way for user interaction and it could be a reject cause. It looks like a debug tool. One thing that could prevent your approval is broke HIG. Are you sure that you need this view in all your screens? May be customized UI elements will be a better way. In case you want to put some parameters to this view, it will be better to put them to settings.

But nobody know what happened after submission before you'll try. :)

Comment: yes, having this view in all my screens would be helpful to me. I would customize the view to look different than that of Apple's.